# How to add Agora.io, Android sdk in Expo?

Tags: react-native, expo, agora.io

I am setting up a new Expo application. How to add the Android SDK of Agora.io to my Expo project?

Answer (score 1):

As pure Expo doesn't support native modules linking and agora.io requires it, you need to eject from Expo.
[Ejecting from expo](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject/)

Comment: This answer needs to be updated with the new EAS Build from Expo

Comment: @NingaCodingTRV could you mention an example or proveide a link showing how to do it properly. I want to integrate a native Android SDK wihtin my Expo project, using Expo Modules. I can't find how to do it!